# why typescript mode don't print error message

Tags: react-native

i use below command to init a project

```
react-native init MyAwesomeProject --template typescript
```

and create a add.tsx file

```
'use strict';  

// this function return string, but it should return number  
function add(left: number, right: number): number{  
    return left + right + 'test';  
}

console.log(add('it is a wrong param', 1));

export default add;
```

add.tsx is imported by App.js. when i run this project, no warning or error is printed, i don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `react-native init MyAwesomeProject --template typescript` sets up a project that can accept typescript code, however it very confusingly doesn't actually set up type checking. Under the hood this is because it sets up Babel (a javscript compiler) which simply strips the TypeScript type annotations. It doesn't actually set up TypeScript itself which would do the actual type checking.

Without seeing your exact project I can't know exactly what you need to fix, but I would suggest following the steps on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/05/07/using-typescript-with-react-native Specifically where it mentions installing typescript ("Adding TypeScript" section), then add a `tsconfig.json` with `{"compilerOptions":{"noEmit": true}}`, and then finally you should be able to run `./node_modules/.bin/tsc` to actually type check your code.

Comment: thank you, i just want to make typescript work, include type checking, i will try as you say